# Android dynamic RelativeLayout and children Views creation

Tags: android, dynamic, android-relativelayout

After numerous questions about this topic I still haven't fully solved the problem.
In the end the first imageview always gets "overwritten" or better said overlapped by another view which should go right of that view.

After extending RelativeLayout is it enough to only override onLayout() method for children view placement? Does onLayout method place all children in one pass or is it called for every specific child? How should that onLayout method implement child placement if I want to use RelativeLayouts specific placemnts (RIGHT_OF, BELOW, etc ...)

In view creation, how can I create a view without layoutparams, is it even possible?

EDIT: Ok I avoided using getWidth in any form and still get bad layout. Icons get first row mixed but full (5 icons), next row has 1 icon only and 2 are missing. At this point I'm quite frustrated because it's a stupid issue and I can't seem to find what's wrong, why doesn't official developer tutorial have more help on dynamic layouts and views?

Log.e from down says:
2: RIGHT OF 1
3: RIGHT OF 2
4: RIGHT OF 3
5: RIGHT OF 4
6: BELOW 1
7: RIGHT OF 6
8: RIGHT OF 7
9: RIGHT OF 8

That's the way it's supposed to be yet it doesn't work, I can't set relative position to layouts that should have been layed out?

```
private void loadResources() {

cursor = managedQuery(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, projection, selection,
null, SORT_BY_COLUMN + " " + SORT_ORDER);
this.startManagingCursor(cursor);

ImageView previousBookmark;

int idOfViewToTheLeft = 1;

if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    bookmarkCounter = 1;
    ByteArrayInputStream blobImage;

    int size = (int) scale * FAVICON_SIZE;
    int screenWidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    int rowBookmarkCount = (int) (screenWidth/(size + scale*leftMargin));

    do{
       bookmark = new ImageView(this);
       bookmark.setId(bookmarkCounter++);
       bookmark.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

       blobImage = new ByteArrayInputStream(
               cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(BookmarkColumns.FAVICON)));

       bookmark.setImageDrawable(
               Drawable.createFromStream(blobImage, "" + bookmark.getId()));

       urls.put(bookmark.getId(),
               cursor.getString(
                        cursor.getColumnIndex(BookmarkColumns.URL)));

       bookmark.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(urls.get(v.getId())));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
            }
        });

       lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(size, size);

       lp.topMargin = (int) (scale * topMargin);
       lp.leftMargin = (int) (scale * leftMargin);
       if(bookmark.getId() > 1) {
           previousBookmark = (ImageView) findViewById(bookmark.getId() - 1);

           if((bookmark.getId() % (rowBookmarkCount + 1)) != 0)
           {
               Log.e("" + bookmark.getId(), "RIGHT OF " + previousBookmark.getId());
               lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, previousBookmark.getId());
           } else {
               Log.e("" + bookmark.getId(), "BELOW " + idOfViewToTheLeft);
               lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, idOfViewToTheLeft);
               idOfViewToTheLeft = bookmark.getId();
           }
       }

       bookmarkLayout.addView(bookmark, lp);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did in the end is quit using relative parameter to describe view's position relative to other view. Instead I did all the math myself and put everything in setMargins, hope that's is equally if not faster than using Relativelayouts methods to figure it out.

```
private void loadResources() {

cursor = managedQuery(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, projection, selection,
null, SORT_BY_COLUMN + " " + SORT_ORDER);
this.startManagingCursor(cursor);

if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    bookmarkCounter = 0;
    ByteArrayInputStream blobImage;

    int leftMargin = (int) (scale * this.leftMargin);
    int topMargin = (int) (scale * this.topMargin);
    int size = (int) scale * FAVICON_SIZE;
    int screenWidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    int rowBookmarkCount = (int) (screenWidth/(size + leftMargin));

    do{
       bookmark = new ImageView(this);
       bookmark.setId(bookmarkCounter++);
       bookmark.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

       blobImage = new ByteArrayInputStream(
               cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(BookmarkColumns.FAVICON)));

       bookmark.setImageDrawable(
               Drawable.createFromStream(blobImage, "" + bookmark.getId()));

       urls.put(bookmark.getId(),
               cursor.getString(
                        cursor.getColumnIndex(BookmarkColumns.URL)));

       bookmark.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(urls.get(v.getId())));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
            }
        });

       lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(size, size);
       lp.setMargins(
               (int) (leftMargin + (bookmark.getId() % rowBookmarkCount) * (size + leftMargin)),
               (int) (topMargin + (bookmark.getId() / rowBookmarkCount) * (size + topMargin)),
               0, 0);
       bookmarkLayout.addView(bookmark, lp);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    setContentView(scrollView);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For standard components you don't really need to override onLayout, if you want for them to layout components as usual that is. If you do override onLayout and don't call super.onLayout then you must position all your children manually.

Otherwise, just use RelativeLayout.LayoutParams with added rules (BELOW, ABOVE, etc..) and set it when adding a view addView(youView, yourLayoutParamsInstance)

Comment: See that's the problem, they told me I can't change view position at creation because I need getwidth method which can't be used in that phase. @AlexOrlov

Comment: If I recall correct, onMeasure is called before the onLayout, that's where you can get dimensions for your layout as imposed by the parent. 
Getting dimensions by getWidth for such a task, in my practice, is pointless and wrong.

Comment: You can override onMeasure and get the width and height passed to your layout, store them somewhere and in the onLayout, knowing all the stuff just do whatever you like.

Comment: And again, if I get everything right, you can get width and stuff as a difference between left and right parameters passed to you in onLayout methods. And, anyway, it is recommended to use getMeasuredWidth instead of getWidth

Answer (score 0):

Most of the logic in `RelativeLayout` actually happens during the measurement phase, so no, just overriding `onLayout` is most likely not enough.

If you want to extend `RelativeLayout`, I'm afraid you'll have to get accustomed to it's source code, otherwise it'll be quite hard to understand how to influence it's behavior. You should really consider finding another solution though, since you really picked one of the more complex classes with `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: hm I avoided extending RelativeLayout but now I can't seem to get view position right. 6 of them are showing rest is probably below one of them.